# How to stop typescript/storybook complaining about a mapped arg type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, storybook

I am trying to create a story using storybook for my `OverflowTooltip` component. JSX Elements aren't JSON Serializable, so I can't pass them directly as args/options to my control, that's why I'm using the mapping feature that's documented [here](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/api/arg-types#mapping) to map the radio control string options to StyledComponents.

However, despite the code actually seeming to work, typescript complains that `'string' is not assignable to ReactElement` while defining the default value in the args property:

```js
import type { Meta } from '@storybook/react';
import { StoryObj } from '@storybook/react';
import { styled } from '@mui/material';
import OverflowTooltip from './overflow-tooltip';

const Child = styled('div')({
    maxWidth: '10em',
    overflow: 'hidden',
    textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
    whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
});

const shortText = 'Short text';
const longText = 'This is a long text that overflows';

const meta: Meta<typeof OverflowTooltip> = {
    component: OverflowTooltip,
    title: 'Packages/Core/Overflow Tooltip',
    args: {
        title: longText,
        children: 'Short', // <--- Typescript complains about this
    },
    argTypes: {
        // ...
        children: {
            name: 'Child Text',
            control: 'radio',
            options: ['Short', 'Long'],
            mapping: {
                Short: <Child>{shortText}</Child>,
                Long: <Child>{longText}</Child>,
            },
            description:
                'If a long text is selected the content will overflow and the tooltip should show up.',
        },
    },
};
```

I have tried omitting that line, but I get the following error:
[image: Error shown while omitting the line]

I have also tried assigning the value directly to the children arg/prop:

```js
children: <Child>{shortText}</Child>
```

but I get the following warning in the console:
[image: Warning shown when directly assigning the non serializable value]

What's the correct way of doing this?